# Visual Studio: How to make its UI fast, lean and minimal?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio can be quite slow to open and work with. The menus and auto-hide windows can get sluggish and commands take a while to start. What are the list of things one can do to make the UI of Visual Studio load **faster** and operate faster? What settings can one change to make it feel **lean** and **minimal**?

PS: I know Visual Studio Express is way leaner and faster. However, I rely on some Visual Studio addons, and addons are not supported in Express.

PS2: I have already closed all unnecessary windows. All diagnostic windows are on auto-hide. And all the tool bars are closed. I work almost completely using keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Please specify version of visual studio, is it vs2008?

Comment: Can you provide machine specs, addons, etc... Can't really answer without first knowing if the problem is not visual studio at all. Because I run vs2010 pro in a vm with 4gb ram and it is very fast.

Comment: Sandy & Spinon: VS2008 and VS2010. I find that 2010 is actually slower. I use the Rockscroll addon on VS2008.

Comment: Neither of the close votes makes sense to me. This *might* be subjective, but... argumentative? And although this is about a piece of software and not about program code, it *is* about an IDE and I think people on SO will have better answers for this than people on SU.

Comment: If you are 24X7 visual studio user, then I'll suggest to bookmark or subscribe feeds from [vsblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/)

Answer (score 14):

Here are some tips, actually collected from following blog posts
###VS2008
[Improve Visual Studio's Source View Performance](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Improve_Visual_Studio%27s_Source_View_Performance.aspx)
[Tips to improve performance of visual studio IDE](https://ashrafur.wordpress.com/2008/03/13/tips-to-improve-performance-of-visual-studio-ide/)
[Visual Studio 2008 Tweaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328135016/http://archcoder.com:80/articles/20100128/visual-studio-2008-tweaks)
###VS2010
[Visual Studio 2010 Performance Part 1: Startup](https://web.archive.org/web/20140731173555/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ricom/archive/2009/05/31/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-1-startup.aspx)
[Visual Studio 2010 Performance Part 2: Text Editor](https://web.archive.org/web/20140503043148/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/05/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-2-text-editor.aspx)
[Visual Studio 2010 Performance Part 3: A Technical Update](https://web.archive.org/web/20160118104610/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/08/19/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-3-a-technical-update.aspx)

###Tips

- Turn off background HTML validation.
  Go to Tools / Options and select Text
  Editor / HTML / Validation in the
  tree view on the left side. Uncheck the Show Errors
  check box.
- Turn off AutoRecover. Go to Tools /
  Options and select Environment /
  AutoRecover in the tree view.
  Uncheck the Save AutoRecover check box.
- Close your property grid (View /
  Properties Window)
- web.config should not have    <compilation batch=”false” />
- Turn off AutoToolboxPopulate (Tools
  -> Options -> Windows Forms Designer set AutoToolboxPopulate False)
- Turn off Track Active item (Tools ->
  Options -> Projects and Solutions
  uncheck Track Active Item in Solution
  Explorer)
- Disable Navigation Bar(Tools ->
  Options -> Text Editor -> C#, uncheck
  Navigation bar)
- Move file in App_Code into a class
  library project
- Disable validation Options for HTML
  Editing (Tools -> Options ->
  Validation -> Clear show error
  checkbox)

Answer (score 2):

I know that VS 2008 slowed down from VS 2005. I feel this pain every once in a while when im doing a quick Find or Find-Replace, or Find-In-Solution...etc. The UI sometimes isn't as fast as your hands are (when you're using keyboard shortcuts).

1. I found that just slowing down sometimes is the way to do it (it sucks, but then again, so does many things about Windows).
2. If it's load times youre concerned about; disable the startup stuff (from the Options menu). Here you can choose to load a blank screen upon VS load AND not to subscribe to any news feeds. (this helps alot depending on your internet connection).
3. you can also, via Options, adjust the visual animations that occur, as well as just disabling them altogether.

If there's anything else im missing, which im sure there is, i'd really like to know as well!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can potentially speed up visual studio is to disable document navigation.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor ->  and uncheck 'Navigation Bar'.

This is definitately an option in 2008, pretty sure its in 2005 too.

Another option to try:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor and Uncheck 'Track Changes'.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the information I posted in the comments I will say the typical stuff. Turn off all addons, if you are using vista or 7 switch to basic vs aero, check all running processes. This is where I would start.