# How to trim down Visual Studio to make it faster?

Tags: visual-studio

A recent exposure to an old IDE that was as almost as responsive as notepad, and [the answers I got about it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38905/what-makes-a-large-and-complex-software-product-slow), got me thinking - Visual Studio must really have a *lot* more stuff that I never use than I thought. It can't all come for free.

So I tried to make a list of things I never use in my Visual Studio:

- Built-in source control
- Team explorer, ServerExplorer, Architecture Explorer, UML model explorer
- Tasks List, Start Page
- Built-in web browser
- Publishing options, MSI maker
- Team Foundation Server integration
- *All* of the database tools - server explorer, schema editor, database sources, and a whole bunch of other stuff. Connect to database/connect to server. Etc.
- Tools: Error Lookup, ATL/MFC trace tool, Spy++, WCF config editor
- The entire Architecture menu. Diagrams, dependency graphs. All unused.
- The entire Test menu. MSTests are just not used here.

And yet, my **add-in manager** lists **zero** add-ins, and my **extension manager** lists **one** extension (color theme editor).

I have read recently that Visual Studio 2010 is essentially all extensions. And I believe that. After all 80% of the things I listed above are absent from the Express edition. It must be possible to rid my Ultimate edition of them too somehow... right?

<sub>It might even look like I don't use *any* Visual Studio from this list, but just to clear this up, I would *not* use another IDE that doesn't have a similarly good editor, debugger, intellisense, profiler, debugger, code navigation tools, refactoring, and did I mention debugger with all of its really handy windows yet?</sub>

Comment: what do you use VS.NET for anyway?

Comment: Is there a performance reason for wanting to disable these? Have you tried Express to see if it's faster without the extra features?

Comment: That is not the MSFT way :) They do not appreciate the Unix philosophy.

Comment: @John good point, I don't know if this would actually help.

Comment: @Phobia C# development. WinForms stuff. Are you hinting at something? :)

Comment: I've added an answer,but I'm not sure whether MonoDevelop supports winforms or not

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279415/visual-studio-how-to-make-its-ui-fast-lean-and-minimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is installing a different edition of VS. You say you have the ultimate edition. You could install the Professional edition instead. It doesn't contain all of that bloated functionality.

Comment: If I'm lucky it won't have anything missing that I actually use, like the profiler.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me you really are looking for **another IDE**, and that depents on what .NET language you are using. For C#, SharpDevelop comes to mind: http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/

OTOH, you could even boil it down to [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and compile through the command line. Notepad++ has code completion, but haven't tested it for all languages.

Comment: Did I mention the debugger yet? :) I guess I shouldn't have mentioned it in such a tiny font :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/download) for windows

I think it's more customizable than VS